# Traverse linked list using Lambda

Tags: c#, lambda, linked-list, traversal

Is it possible to traverse (IE: Find an element) in a linked list using Lambda? My assumption is that it isn't?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, if you're using the .Net implementation of [LinkedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx). Since it implements `IEnumerable<T>` you can use LINQ against it. If you meant whether you can use Lambda specifically, then you can do the following to use it recursively.

```
Func<Node, Node> getLastNode = null;
getLastNode = n => n.IsLast? n : getLastNode(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have these usings at the top

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
```

Then you can do something like

```
var found = ll.FirstOrDefault ( o => o.SomeProperty == 1 );
```